# Dealing with request limits

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, semaphore

I have a very large number of errors occurring in production right now, mostly timeouts and this:

> Exception type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Exception message: Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 180 and has been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance.

After some investigation, I followed the MSDN guide and looked at the **sys.dm_exec_requests** table, specifically for 'suspended' requests. I found a bunch, all of them of type **RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE**. As I understand it, this happens when the query doesn't have sufficient memory to execute, so it's put in a queue until the resources free up to run it. I'd like to investigate further, to at least see what exact queries are causing problems, by using `sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores` and `sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants`, but those are not available in Sql Azure. So I'm kind of stumped.

Since this morning, my production db has been running smoothly for 10-15 minutes, followed by 10-15 minutes of the request limit getting hammered and timing out. Rinse and repeat all day. We haven't made any changes to our data layer in at least a month and we've never seen this problem, so I'm trying to figure out where to go from here.

Comment: Throttling?  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3507.windows-azure-sql-database-performance-and-elasticity-guide.aspx

Comment: We have a multiplicative retry policy in place that will stand off when it gets timeout errors (waiting 2 seconds, then 4, then 6, then 8, then 10 before giving up). This is a different problem, where it seems the entire sql server instance was choking. The exec_requests table filled with 180 'suspended' queries every few minutes, so it's not so much throttling as it is a complete traffic jam.